# I have a problem to Install SimRAD package

Tags: r

library(SimRAD)
Error: package ‘Biostrings’ required by ‘SimRAD’ could not be found

> install.packages("Biostrings")
> WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Ali Basuony/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘Biostrings’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)

> 

Comment: As the warning message indicates, you will need to install [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/history.html) (Rtools35.exe if you're using R 3.6.3) first.

Comment: Thanks for help. I installed Rtools35.exe and still have the same problem.> library(SimRAD)
Error: package ‘Biostrings’ required by ‘SimRAD’ could not be found
> install.packages("Biosstrings")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Ali Basuony/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘Biosstrings’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)
>

Comment: That looks like a typo: the package is 'Biostrings' not 'Biosstrings'. See also guidance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa) for resolving this issue (this looks like problem 1 in the accepted answer).